# Multiple config files: Which one do the process read from?

Tags: .net, web-config, app-config

I have a solution with multiple projects. In each project I've added a .config file with settings that affect the local settings.

When I tried to read the settings for the database connection, I got some values which I don't know where they come from.

This is the .config file of DatabaseLayer Solution:

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="localDBConnection"
        connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Niko\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\GaitLinkServer\DatabaseLayer\GaitLinkDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I executed the line

```
private string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["localDBConnection"].ToString();
```

I've got the null reference object exception. So I tried to execute the following command:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0]
```

and it returned

```
{data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true}
base {System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement}: {data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true}
ConnectionString: "data source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
Name: "LocalSqlServer"
ProviderName: "System.Data.SqlClient"
```

Which don't know where does it come from.

I would really appreciate if anyone could show how to make a global .config file for a solution with multiple projects and how to link local (Project) .config files.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a note, if you use ApplicationSettings, the properties get defaults from whatever App.Config file was part of that particular project.  You can specify the Application Settings in the running application, which will override the defaults.

To explain..

I have a project called CatalogData.  Using the Project properties screen / Settings tab, I added a property called test, with value of test.

The Application Configuration file contains

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
```

...

```
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="userSettings" 
     type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
    >
        <section name="CatalogModel.Properties.Settings"
         type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
         allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<userSettings>
    <CatalogModel.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="test" serializeAs="String">
            <value>test</value>
        </setting>
    </CatalogModel.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

...

```
</configuration>
```

The code generated to read the setting (make it available via My.Settings.test for VB.NET or as follows in C#

```
CatalogModel.Properties.Settings s = new CatalogModel.Properties.Settings();
string test = s.test;
```

Gets defaulted in the generated code, which effectively makes the app.config file unnecessary for deployment so long as the compiled settings are OK.

In this snippet, you can see the attribute which gives the default, which is compiled.

```
...
    [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("test")]

    public string test {
        get {
            return ((string)(this["test"]));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A given AppDomain (not a process, actually), always reads configuration data from a single file. By default, this is *applicationname*.EXE.CONFIG for a desktop application, or web.config for an asp.net application. No .DLL.CONFIG is ever used. You will need to copy any settings from such a file into the real configuration file.

Comment: This is a bit old I know but why is a dll.config file created if it's never used? I have an asp.net app with a web.config file. When I build the project I end up with a MyAppName.dll.config file in the /bin folder. It looks like it's not used (and it's identical to the web.config file) so I'm wondering why it's created in the first place.

Comment: It stores the settings that will need to be merged into the appropriate .exe.config or web.config. Otherwise, where would the settings be stored?

Comment: I'm a bit confused: I have a web.config file and it's only after I build the asp.net app that I end up with a MyAppName.dll.config file in the /bin folder Basically I end up with 1 web.config file and 1 MyAppName.dll.config file. They are identical and the 2nd one is clearly not used. This only happened when I started using Visual Studio 2013. Before the upgrade I only had the web.config file.

Comment: @Anthony: Your web.config file is unlikely to be identical to your MyDll.dll.config file.

Comment: I can assure you the 2 config files are identical (I've just compared them again). In fact one is called web.config (as expected) and the other one MyWebApp.dll.config It's like Visual Studio was taking the web.config file and was renaming it MyWebApp.dll.config before putting in the /bin folder. It's clearly not needed as when I delete it the web app works as expected. I'm just wondering why this extra config file is created and how I can prevent this from happening if it's not necessary.

Comment: @Anthony: Well, I've never heard of such a thing. Are you using a web application project (File-New Project), or a web site (File->New Web Site)?

Comment: It's a web application project. The problem only started when I switch edto Visual Studio 2013 (from Visual Studio 2012) without changing anything in the code or anywhere else. Anyway, thanks for your time. It's not really a big deal but I'll try to figure out what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

All of your config settings need to go in the app.config (or web.config) for the executable project (your console app, website, etc.).

If you put config settings in the app.config for a library (DLL) project, they will not be found.  You need to copy all the settings into the .config for the executable.  Or you can mess with the build action for your DLL project app.configs, then try to reference those from your executable app.config.  Usually it's easiest to just put all the settings in one place though.

Answer (score 0):

One thing not mentioned to the answers give so far is that any assembly running in the ASP.NET or WinForms app will recognize the application's web.config/app.config via the ConfigurationManager. So, as suggested, when you put the config info into the app's config file, the assemblies used in the app can read those values. The only thing you have to do (and document as good practice), is make sure the app/web config has a named element that the .DLL expects.

For example, you have a .DLL in a WinForms app that expects the application hosting the .DLL to have an entry in  named "MyAppConn". Your DLL's code would use:

```
Dim cs as String = ConfigurtionManager.ConnectionStrings("MyAppConn").ToString
```

The DLL can be used in many different hosting applications, and as long as MyAppConn is defined in the hosting app's .config file, the DLL will get the connection string. MyAppConn can point to different databases in each hosting app, if desired.